# Angular 6 Testing Jasmine Karma: Override Provider Not working

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So i've looked at many issues online including this one 
https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/320
and i'm stumped...

How I have my code set up is that I have my main describe create my testbed component, Here I have my mockParams set up for the active route so we can this.route.queryparams.subscribe(..), My problem is I am unable to overwrite the values in a different describe or 'it' block.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule
        })],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockParams },
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Here is an example of me adding a the override in a different NESTED describe block...

```
beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.overrideProvider(ActivatedRoute, 
      {useValue: newMockParams});
      TestBed.compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

It's almost like this doesnt run at all... the new mock params do not change if i re-use mockParams and change the values then it will change the value in the original describe, Do I really have to re-create my component in every nested describe? It just doesn't feel right that I would have to do so when the only thing I need to change is the provider, i'm unsure what overrideProvider even does at this point! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 4):

### Updated with new information provided in comments below.

My suggestion is to change the value returned  by route.queryParams.  You mentioned in the comments that your ngOnInit() function looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { this.value = params; });
}
```

If you change the return value from the queryParams observable before running .detectChanges() in each test, this should achieve what you want.  For example, something like this:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let mockActivatedRoute = {queryParams: of({old: 'test'})};
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let route: ActivatedRoute;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            imports: [ ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
    });

    it('ngOnInit should initialize and route params be intial values', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges(); // execute ngOnInit() in component
        expect(component.value).toEqual({old: 'test'}); // check that value is correct
    });
        it('ngOnInit should initialize and route params be changed values', () => {
        route.queryParams = of({new: 'newTest'/* mocked params */});
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.value).toEqual({new: 'newTest'}); // check that value is correct
    });
});
```

I tested this all in a stackblitz to be sure this all works error free.  :)  Here is the link: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-52936483?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts)

Comment: I do not use a get, I use the value direction

`ngOnInit() {
    this.route.query.subscribe(params => {
        this.value = params;
    });
}`

Comment: I'm guessing you actually mean `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { this.value = params; })`?  I will update my answer.

Comment: yes my apologies, could you tell me where you are getting the 'get' from? I'm getting an error _'Property queryParams does not have access type get'_

Comment: As I was answering your comment, I realized I over-complicated my answer a bit with using spyOnProperty.  I have a cleaner solution for you, but I am thinking this would be easier if I showed you in a Stackblitz and then you can fork it yourself and play around with different tests.  I will update my answer with this new info.